# Cubemap texturing issue D3D11 (C++)

Tags: c++, textures, directx

I have a texture problem with the cubemap I'm rendering and can't seem to figure it out. I've generated a cube map with direct x's texture tools and then read it using

```
D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(device, L"cubemap.dds", 0, 0, &fullcubemap, 0);
```

The cubemap texture is not high quality at all and it looks really stretched/distorted. I can definitely tell that the images used for the cubemap match correctly, but it's not great at all at the moment

[image]

I'm not sure why this is happening. Is it because my textures are too large/small or is it something else? If it's due to the size of the textures, what is a recommended texture size? I am using a sphere for the cubemap not a cube.

Edit:

Shader:

```
cbuffer SkyboxConstantBuffer {
    float4x4 world;
    float4x4 view;
    float4x4 projection;
};

TextureCube gCubeMap;

SamplerState samTriLinearSam {
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
};

struct VertexIn {
    float4 position : POSITION;
};

struct VertexOut {
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 spherePosition : POSITION;
};

VertexOut VS(VertexIn vin) {
    VertexOut vout = (VertexOut)0;

    vin.position.w = 1.0f;

    vout.position = mul(vin.position, world);
    vout.position = mul(vout.position, view);
    vout.position = mul(vout.position, projection);

    vout.spherePosition = vin.position;

    return vout;
}

float4 PS(VertexOut pin) : SV_Target {
    return gCubeMap.Sample(samTriLinearSam, pin.spherePosition);//float4(1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
}

RasterizerState NoCull {
    CullMode = None;
};

DepthStencilState LessEqualDSS {
    DepthFunc = LESS_EQUAL;
};

technique11 SkyTech {
    pass p0 {
        SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_4_0, VS()));
        SetGeometryShader(NULL);
        SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_4_0, PS()));

        SetRasterizerState(NoCull);
        SetDepthStencilState(LessEqualDSS, 0);
    }
}
```

Draw:

```
immediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &renderTarget, nullptr);

XMMATRIX sworld, sview, sprojection;
SkyboxConstantBuffer scb;
sview = XMLoadFloat4x4(&_view);
sprojection = XMLoadFloat4x4(&_projection);
sworld = XMLoadFloat4x4(&_world);

scb.world = sworld;
scb.view = sview;
scb.projection = sprojection;

immediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer(cubeMapSphere->getIndexBuffer(), DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
ID3D11Buffer*  vertexBuffer = cubeMapSphere->getVertexBuffer();
//ID3DX11EffectShaderResourceVariable * cMap;
////cMap = skyboxShader->GetVariableByName("gCubeMap")->AsShaderResource();
immediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &fullcubemap);//textures
//cMap->SetResource(fullcubemap);
immediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
immediateContext->VSSetShader(skyboxVertexShader, nullptr, 0);
immediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &skyboxConstantBuffer);
immediateContext->PSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &skyboxConstantBuffer);
immediateContext->PSSetShader(skyboxPixelShader, nullptr, 0);

immediateContext->UpdateSubresource(skyboxConstantBuffer, 0, nullptr, &scb, 0, 0);
immediateContext->DrawIndexed(cubeMapSphere->getIndexBufferSize(), 0, 0);
```

Initially I was planning to use this snippet to update the TextureCube variable in the shader

```
ID3DX11EffectShaderResourceVariable * cMap;
cMap = skyboxShader->GetVariableByName("gCubeMap")->AsShaderResource();
cMap->SetResource(fullcubemap);
```

But it seems that has no effect, and in fact, without the following line, the sphere I'm using for the cubemap textures with a texture used with another object in the scene, so perhaps there's something going on here? I'm not sure what though.

```
immediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &fullcubemap);//textures
```

Edit: Probably not the above, realised that if this wasn't updated, the old texture would be applied as it's never wiped after each draw.

Edit: Tried the cubemap with both a sphere and a cube, still the same texture issue.

Edit: Tried loading the shader resource view differently

```
D3DX11_IMAGE_LOAD_INFO loadSMInfo;
loadSMInfo.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE;

ID3D11Texture2D* SMTexture = 0;
hr = D3DX11CreateTextureFromFile(device, L"cubemap.dds",
    &loadSMInfo, 0, (ID3D11Resource**)&SMTexture, 0);

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC SMTextureDesc;
SMTexture->GetDesc(&SMTextureDesc);

D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC SMViewDesc;
SMViewDesc.Format = SMTextureDesc.Format;
SMViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURECUBE;
SMViewDesc.TextureCube.MipLevels = SMTextureDesc.MipLevels;
SMViewDesc.TextureCube.MostDetailedMip = 0;

hr = device->CreateShaderResourceView(SMTexture, &SMViewDesc, &fullcubemap);
```

Still produces the same output, any ideas?

Edit: Tried increasing the zfar distance and the texture remains the exact same no matter what value I put.

Example with second texture with increased view distance.
[image]

This texture is used on another object in my scene and comes out fine.

Comment: Two possibilities come to mind: 1) your shader or render state are reading from a very small mip level of the texture or 2) you're using an orthographic camera or very narrow fov which tends to exaggerate the apparent scale of distant objects (like a sky at infinity). Can you give more details about your rendering/shader setup so we can diagnose this in more detail?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated my post with my shader and draw code, if there's anything else that you need to see just let me know.

Comment: Still no luck, tried a few things and it still comes out the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the sphere you're rendering centred at the origin in local space? The parameter you pass for sampling the cubemap should be a direction.

Comment: @Adam I believe so. Is it not currently taking a direction? The texturing I believe is fine, it's just really zoomed in. If I could somehow move it further away it would look fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be that I needed to use XMMatrixTranspose